# Vim - Formatting UTF-8 Text with Par (Paragraph Reformatter)

Tags: windows, vim

Being looking for a definite answer whether the `UTF-8 patch` for `par` (paragraph reformatter, available [here](http://www.nicemice.net/par/)) also works under `Windows`.

So far, I reckon an easier but less reliable way to format and `justify UTF-8 text` with `unpatched par` under Windows is to

```
  :set encoding=utf-8
  :set fileencoding=latin1
```

before executing

```
  par -j
```

Afterwards, re-set the file encoding with

```
  :set fileencoding=utf-8
```

I wonder if anyone has similar experience.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the Windows console executable inside the file `par152wc.zip` on the site you linked to supports Unicode.

You can add the following to your `_vimrc` to use `par` as the default formatter (assuming it's in your path):

```
if executable("par")
    set formatprg=par\ -qw78
endif
```

This will use `par` when doing <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>q</kbd>; Vim's internal formatter is still available via <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>w</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks for replying. After giving it a try, the `WIN32 version` does the same thing as the `unpatched (ASCII) version` which I compile with MinGW. So, I guess the WIN32 version uses the original source code. Both versions have no problem to process Unicode if `the justify option -j` is not given. I think a clearer description of my wee question can be found on [here](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=310495). After countless trial-and-error (coz I got no programming skill), I reckon Windows console treats a file encoded by UTF-8 differently than that of UTF-16 or Latin1.

Comment: Ah, okay. I just know it works for non-ASCII characters in UFT-8-encoded text when left-aligning to a certain width. I generally avoid full justification because of the [rivers of white](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/River_(typography)) you get.